# Unable to return the default value of dictionary in web api

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-web-api2

In my `WEB API` I am trying to return a default value of my dictionary variable so that I can handle any exception/error.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var error = "06";
        string key = "default";
        try
        {
            var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.Even, 8, StopBits.One);
            //serial port settings and opening it
            serialPort.Open();

            var stream = new SerialStream(serialPort);
            stream.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            // send request and waiting for response
            // the request needs: slaveId, dataAddress, registerCount            
            var responseBytes = stream.RequestFunc3(slaveId, dataAddress, registerCount);

            // extract the content part (the most important in the response)
            var data = responseBytes.ToResponseFunc3().Data;

            var finalData = floatArray(data);


            //var result = data.Where(r => r > 0).Select(r => r.ToString()).ToArray();
             dict = finalData.Select((b, i) => (value: b, index: i)) // convert bytes to sequence of (byte value, index)
                                .ToDictionary(x => x.index.ToString(), x => x.value.ToString());

            serialPort.Close();

            return dict;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return dict.TryGetValue(key, out error);
        }
```

I am using a client to send an error message so that I can verify my `try..catch`. But I am unable to set  a default value to my `dict` variable as I am getting below error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'

How can I achieve it ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The full API controller method signature is needed to be sure that what I'm seeing is what's happening, but it appears you are returning a `bool` in a method which tries to return a dictionary. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**TryGetValue**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8) : Get `Value` by `Key` and return a `bool`, you could change the `catch`, like the following code:

```
try
{
...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    dict.Add(key, error);
    return dict;
}
```

I hope this help.